# PNP Detected Fatal Error

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

I have a Dell E5550 laptop which goes to a blue screen of death (BSOD) about one to three minutes after booting.

It has an error message which tells me to tell a support person:

> PNP Detected Fatal Error

It then reboots a couple of times, eventually leading to the screen where I can try "Start-up repair", but that fails and tells me that start-up repair couldn't repair it.

If I then get through a couple more of the same BSOD, I can get to "System Restore". Performing a system restore to the latest one available takes me back to the beginning of the problem, and I don't have long enough to try installing the latest drivers from Dell to try to fix it. It will let me boot into Safe Mode with Networking, but I can't install/uninstall anything in safe mode.

I took the SSD out and ran chkdsk on it on another computer, and there were no problems.

How can I get it to stay alive long enough to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by third-party driver update software – when the machine starts up, it takes a minute or two for that software to have an effect.

The reason it is stable in Safe Mode with Networking is that the unwanted software doesn't get loaded in that mode.

You can defeat it by disconnecting the PC from the internet (switch off the WiFi; unplug the Ethernet lead), going through the System Restore again so it will boot normally, and then you can examine the installed apps for anything with a name which suggests it might do driver updates, such as "Driver Support One", and uninstalling it.

Restart the machine, connect it to the internet, and leave it for a while to confirm the problem has gone. Install the latest drivers from the manufacturer, restart, and leave it running for a while to make sure everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue in the past couple days on my Dell E5550 and I located it down to a recent but bad Intel driver update in a Windows update.

The suspect is the driver update "Intel - System - 8.3.10209.6897".

[image]

(The above can be found by searching for "View your Update History" in Windows start menu). To temporarily fix this, in Safe Mode go to Device Manager and disable the "Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework" drivers. Try rebooting afterwards.

[image]

"PNP" stands for Plug and Play which indicates a driver issue. If this does not work, it is likely to be an issue with another driver. Try going through the list, disabling drivers and restarting to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: That does make me wonder if the third-party driver update software was installing that particular update.